# Я хочу добавить функцию при которой персонаж может стоять на любом окне, как в игре Outcore: Desktop Adventure. Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я делаю приложение на Unity 2D, в котором персонаж может передвигаться по рабочему столу, я хочу добавить функцию при которой персонаж может стоять на любом окне, как в игре Outcore: Desktop Adventure. Какие WinAPI мне понадобятся, если дело не в WinAPI, то как это сделать?

Comment: Данные о координатах и размере окон можно получить из WinAPI, всё верно. Но есть нюанс, помимо Win32 окон в современной винде (начиная с Windows 8) есть еще WinRT окна (приложения WinStore), информация о которых получается уже через другое API, и оно Win32-приложению может оказаться недоступным, поэтому потребуется какое-то прокси-приложение, которое будет добывать эти данные. То есть это реализуемо, но весьма непросто. Вопрос слишком общий, вряд-ли на него можно конкретно ответить.